# What is the fastest way to crystallise lysozyme (for student course)?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, lab-techniques, xray-crystallography

High school sudents are going to visit my university and I plan to demonstrate crystallisation of lysozyme. I ordered pure lysozyme from VWR. I can easily crystallise this within 15 min in batch (4% w/v NaCl, 35 mg/mL Lysozyme dissolved in 0.2M NaAc). However, as many different student groups will go through this experiment sequentially, it is preferable that it takes even less time (5 min waiting time maximum). I can of course try to optimise this on my own, but I am wondering if anyone has experience with the absolute fastest way lysozyme forms crystals in a batch setup (to save time and chemicals).

**In summary:** What are the most optimal buffer/pH/lysozyme concentrations that will give crystals (in a batch experiment) within a very short timeframe (<5-6 min)?

Comment: I think you have better chances to find an answer here than on [chemistry.se]. Your question is on-topic on both sites.

Comment: Check this out https://hamptonresearch.com/product_detail.aspx?cid=28&sid=173&pid=524

Comment: Cool, I could try this out and report back

Comment: I don't have an expertise in this field but don't you think 15min is quite fast? Most biology protocols take much longer. I have seen protein-crystallography people waiting for several days to get their protein to crystallize.

Comment: Yes it is, my PhD-project crystal normally take about 3-4-day. However, lysozyme is insanely easy to crystallise - and this is for a open research day with high-school student that have a very limited time to conduct the experiment. I just think its interesting to get the absolute optimal way of doing this fast. The answer may be that its not possible in less than 15 min (but I dont know).

Comment: Perhaps you could start a new crystallization with each group (every 5 min) and then show them the results of previous groups. Each group could then be able to observe what is happening at 0, 5, 10 and 15 min.

Comment: One try would be to see if also for lysozyme a powder of previously generated lysozyme crystals would nucleate and hence speed up the crystallization if added to lysozyme solution.